# how to get result of multiple EditText on a Text View without using button

Tags: android

I want the Total in a Text View(can't see now but it is mentioned below the last Edit Text(10x)).. You can see the question in Image

[image]

Comment: Use [TextWatcher](http://www.learn2crack.com/2014/02/android-textwatcher-example.html)

Comment: please explain this to vague to answer

Comment: @Amrit Sharma : Add what you have tried so far ?

Answer (score 0):

You do the following for all of the EditTexts you have

```
editText1000x.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

      public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        int sum = Integer.parseInteger(editText1000x.getText()) * 1000;
        sum += Integer.parseInteger(editText500x.getText()) * 500;
        //and so forth for all the other editTexts.

        textView.setText("" + sum);

      }

      public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {}

      public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {}
});
```